# Deprecated issue in electric regarding one of scan member functions

Tags: roscpp, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a line of code that has deprecated issue in *electric* and I would like to know what is its better substitute.

Issue:

=> scan.set_ranges_size((int)(90/0.25));

[Warning:*‘void sensor_msgs::LaserScan_::set_ranges_size(uint32_t) [with ContainerAllocator = std::allocator]’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/
sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h:85)*]

P/S: Waiting for @joq's answer for he has done it already. This post is a refactor one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12450/deprecated-issue-in-electric-regarding-one-of-scan-member-functions/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-24**:
Another one is here: http://answers.ros.org/question/3420/deprecated-issue-regarding-btquaternion-in

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-24**:
@joq: Thanks a lot for the suggesting of dividing them. Yes, it's indeed better for the community.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-24**:
I've just divided them, could you please cut and paste your previous answer accordingly. Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-12-24**:
It would probably work better for others with similar problems to divide this into two separate questions: one for set_ranges_size and another for the btQuaternion constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the `std::vector` `resize` method directly:

```
scan.ranges.resize((int)(90/0.25));
```

Be careful of that `(int)` cast. I believe the floating point result will be exact in this example, so truncation should not be an issue. Generally, it is better to round explicitly.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1